# How to address my boss?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, guatemala

My company has its own flavor of [Spotify's organizational structure.](http://www.full-stackagile.com/2016/02/14/team-organisation-squads-chapters-tribes-and-guilds/) I reside within a squad where my Squad Lead acts as both the Product Owner and the Scrum Master. I take "orders" from him, but I would put him on more of a "Peer" level than a "Boss" level in a hierarchical sense.

He's originally from Guatemala and I want to address him in Spanish that would properly reflect such an organization.

He's 15 years my senior, but I think "Señor" is too formal.

He often calls me "dude," to which translates "cuate" (according to him).

He is okay with me calling him "cuate" but I don't know if that's too informal.

Comment: How would you address him in English?

Comment: After seeing the first answer I think you should give examples of situations you are interested in. It is not the same when you say hello in the morning as when you are having a meeting and you want to talk about him with him being present or with him being absent. In the morning you could say "hola cuate" / "hola amigo" but it might not be nice if you tell other people "I was working with my _cuate_ on this"

Comment: From here http://villagt.com/palabras-guatemaltecas.html I guess you could say hello to this guy like this **qué onda cuate** and he should find that funny and be ok with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's sounds like you want to address your colleague informally, with an expression of friendly esteem, but with an additional measure of respect because he's your senior in age and experience/skill.  But not so much additional respect that you would no longer feel like teammates.  This is going to vary a lot from place to place.  "Compa" (an affectionate shorthand for "compañero") might work well in some places.

In Mexico, there's a great word for this.  There are two versions.  Say his name is Raúl.

> 1. Maestro
> 2. Maestro Raúl

Examples of use:

> Hola, buenos días, Maestro Raúl.  ¿Cómo amaneciste?  [Or ¿Cómo te va? etc.]
>
> Hola, maestro. *This is good when you're in a hurry.*

I don't know if this is popular in Guatemala, but since it's a neighbor of Mexico, hopefully he'd be comfortable with this.  The major possible drawback is that it can be tricky for an Anglo to pronounce.  There is a variant of the pronunciation that you *might* be able to get away with: "Maistro."

One step up on the respect and formality axis is

> Don Raúl

He might feel put off by this, though.  It kind of depends on exactly what customs he grew up with.  Therefore, I would suggest that you set up an example relationship, and ask him what honorific *he* would use.  I will assume for the following that you typically speak with him in English (let me know if that's wrong).  This would be something to ask over lunch, when you've got some time to shoot the breeze.

> Raúl, I have a question about Spanish.  When you were growing up, back in Guatemala, let's say you had a neighbor, a youngish adult, and your parents had trained you to call him "Don Roberto."  Now let's imagine that when you grew up you ended up working with him.  Let's say you couldn't just call him "Roberto" -- it just didn't feel right -- then what would you call him?

Comment: Interesting...
Reading the translation, `Maestro` seems like a formal teacher --A Professor.
In English, Maestro is mostly used in the Italian sense --an expert musician or conductor. [wikipedia](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Maestro)

Comment: @TedArmstrong - That is one use.  There are others, including a slangy sign of respect among peers.  Sorry, I should have explained.

Comment: If I were to use Maestro, would I append his first or last name? (We're on a first-name basis)

Comment: Well, since you normally use his first name, you would use his first name, as in the example ("Maestro Raúl").  But you just have to feel him out to see if this works with guatemaltecos.  There are lots of subtleties to this word in Mexico.  For example, it can be used with carpenters.  It can be used in a chiding, teasing way among college students.  There are lots of different uses.  Bottom line, if in doubt, ask (e.g. "Te molesta si te digo 'Maestro Raúl'?" or "Is it okay to call you 'Maestro Raúl'?")  It sounds like he is a ...

Comment: very easy-going guy, and the worst that could happen would be that he might find it mildly amusing -- but wouldn't take offense.  Don't forget to update us!

Comment: Nice point about the trickiness of pronunciation! I said "Maistro" and he chuckled, then corrected me with  "ma estro"

Answer (score 1):

As you say, neither a scrum master nor a product owner are technically your boss (el *jefe*), and that person is already addressing you as "cuate". It is true that he might be more senior, but if I understand that organizational model you want your squads, guilds or whatever you want to call them (they are referred as *scrum teams* in my organization) to have a "flat" structure. The *principal* (software engineer) and the *seniors* in my team are my *buddies* rather than my *superiors*. It would be perfectly fine your you to address him back as `cuate` as well.

So my suggestions to address this person would be:

- colega
- compañero
- compadre
- socio

and the like. You could use also "jefe" or señor" if you do it in a playful way. "Sí señor" is the equivalent of "Yes sir". You could use it here or there without meaning that there is a "difference in rank" between the two of you. Of course these two should not be your "go to" nouns to address this person. "Amigo/a" could work as well, since it is just a plain translation for "friend".

Answer (score 1):

You should consider not calling him anything.

Why say "Good morning, dude!" or "Good morning, sir!" when you can say "Good morning!" :)

In English, often the way you call someone is the main indicator of (in)formality, but in Spanish we have the vos/tú/usted treatments. In this case, you should use "vos" (since he's from Guatemala and you want something that sounds natural to him) or "tú" if you have learnt Spanish from a country that uses "tú" and don't feel comfortable with "vos".

Then there's the first name, which would be adequate in this case and is OK in a wide range of formality levels, from the most informal to the mildly formal, even sometimes with "usted). So, e.g.: to get his attention if his looking the other way you could say:

> ¡Oye!
>
> ¡Oye, Juan!
>
> ¡Juan!

For a greeting:

> "¡Hola! ¿Cómo estás?"

That is not formal (as would be "¿Cómo está usted?") but it is also nothing that could offend anyone (except the king or a pissed off policeman :-) ).

I think that is the safest choice.

Comment: Let's at least include his name in the greeting -- the OP would like a *warm* greeting (e.g. "¡Hola, Juan! ¿Cómo estás?").

Comment: Yes, that would definitely add warmth to it (at least in writing, in speach, warmth would be determined more by the intonation), and without affecting the level of formality or informality. It would be a good addition.

Comment: A couple members of my family are a bit on the Asperger's side, and they have trouble using people's names.  My observation has been that it does make a difference.

Comment: I'm sure in English it has a much larger effect than in Spanish. To us, Spanish speakers, it's even odd when in dubbed films one of the characters asks "Is it OK if I call you [christian-name]?". The actual equivalent in Spanish to being "on a first-name basis" would be "tutearse" (i.e.: address one another by "tú" or "vos"). So in Spanish, yeap, it might add warmth, but no, it won't change the formality level, and in particular, not using it will not make "¿Cómo estás?" sound formal; that would require switching to usted: "¿Cómo está?".

Comment: No argument with anything you said.  But I'm talking about emotional warmth, which is a somewhat different axis than the formal-informal axis.